# Finding recursion relation in renormalization group theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, ising-model

I'm trying to learn statistical mechanics by studying the book by Plischke and Bergersen, but I'm stuck with how to find the recursion relation (which can be used to find the fixed points) in renormalization group theory. On page 267 in PB (7.5.1 Finite lattice methods) the following example is given

Consider the Ising ferromagnet on a triangular lattice with the "majority rule" projection. The renormalized Hamiltonian takes the form

$e^{g(K)+H'(K',\mu)}=e^{g+K'\mu_I\mu_J}=Tr_\sigma P(\mu,\{\sigma\})exp(K\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}\sigma_i \sigma_j)$

The functions $g$ and $K'$ can be determined by noting that

$e^{g+K'}=Tr_\sigma P(\mu_i=+1,\{\sigma\})P(\mu_J=+1,\{\sigma\})e^H$
$e^{g-K'}=Tr_\sigma P(\mu_i=+1,\{\sigma\})P(\mu_J=-1,\{\sigma\})e^H$

Because of the restriction placed on the trace by the projection operator ($P$), sixteen terms contribute in each case. We obtain

$e^{g+K'}=e^{8K}+3e^{4K}+2e^{2K}+3+6e^{-2K}+e^{-4K}$

$e^{g-K'}=2e^{4K}+2e^{2K}+4+6e^{-2K}+2e^{-4K}$

Now, I wonder how we get from the expressions with the traces and projection operators to the sums of exponentials? I understand it is possible to do it by going through all combinations of spins, but this is very time consuming for larger systems. The authors of the book seem to think it is obvious how to go between these two expressions as they never really explain the intermediate steps. Therefore I hope someone can provide these intermediate steps.

Comment: It's done by going through all spin combinations literally. And occasionally it's too time consuming (and sometimes impossible) to perform this procedure for more complicated models.